# How to install and manage multiple versions of R

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

I am working on a machine that has older version of R. I don't have root access on the machine, and the sys admin is on a vacation.

So the question I have is, how can I install and manage (the packages, especially) the latest version of R? Obviously I need to download the R package and install it, but a few detailed instructions from the community will help.

R noob here. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the Linux download page on CRAN? http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/

Comment: This is in the documentation. You can install it per user and create a specific user library.